# Can we pass instance of subclass instead of superclass as method/constructor argument?

Tags: java

I have a class A

```
class A {
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

BB is a subclass of B

```
class BB extends B {
    //some code
}
```

Is it possible to call the constructor of A using an instance of BB instead of an instance of B?

```
BB b = new BB();
//          ↓ - BB instead of declared B
A a = new A(b);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It worked, but I'm not sure whether it is correct or not

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Any instance of E is an instance of B. As long as your E doesn't break any of the functionality of B, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tried to simplify and clarify your question (BB seems like better name for subtype of B instead of E and you didn't really need/use more fields in class which made it unnecessary more confusing so I removed them). Anyway what you are doing is fine since any subclass can also be treated as representation of superclass. Just like `pet(Animal a)` can handle any Animal subtypes like `Cat` `Dog` etc.